# How to check if a txt file exists in android

Tags: android

What I want is a peace of code that checks if a text file exists. I'm using java.

What I want is something like this:

```
if (the file.txt exists)  { do a action } else {do another action }
```

The file is in the file directory in the data folder of the app. Thanks! :P

EDIT: I save the file like this:

```
public class crear_data_mes {
    String nArchivo_mes = "mes.txt";
    Context ctx_mes;
    FileOutputStream fos_mes;
    FileInputStream fis_mes;
    public crear_data_mes(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx_mes=ctx;
    }
    public void escribir_mes(String textoarchivo_mes) {
        try {
            fos_mes= ctx_mes.openFileOutput(nArchivo_mes, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos_mes.write(textoarchivo_mes.getBytes());
            fos_mes.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("Hola", "Hola" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("Hola", "Hola"+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public String leer_mes () {
        String lectura_mes = "";
        try {

            fis_mes = ctx_mes.openFileInput(nArchivo_mes);
            int i;
            int n_mes = 0;
            char caracter_mes='a';
            do {
                i = fis_mes.read();
                if (i!='\n') {
                    caracter_mes = (char)i;
                    lectura_mes=lectura_mes+caracter_mes;
                }
            } while (i>0);
            lectura_mes+="\n";
        } catch (Exception e) { }
        return lectura_mes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File` has the [exists()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#exists()) method, that does what you need.

```
File file = new File(fileDirectory, "file.txt");
if (file.exists()) {

}
```

where `fileDirectory` is the directory where you stored the file.

Edit:

in your case you can use [getFileStreamPath](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFileStreamPath(java.lang.String)), which returns the absolute path on the filesystem where a file created with openFileOutput(String, int) is stored.

E.g.

```
File file = getFileStreamPath("file.txt");
if (file.exists()) {

}
```

Comment: Where is the file directory? I mean it's only the predetermitated directory

Comment: how did you create the file ?

Comment: how did you store it ?